# Trying to render dynamic dropdowns using Bootstrap and Marionette, sibling tag

Tags: backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

```
<div class="dropdown">
  <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
    <li role="presentation">
      <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{model.name}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

This is the basic code that bootstrap needs for a dropdown

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel"></ul>
```

That is the code I need to be rendered as a item for a menu (File, Edit, etc...) the problem are the sibling tags that hold the menu list items

I would use something like this:

```
<a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">{{name}}</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel"></ul>
```

Then I want to render menu list items into the 'ul.dropdown-menu' element:

```
<li role="presentation">
   <a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="#">{{name}}</a>
</li>
```

Here is my Marionette view:

```
var menuItem = Marionette.ItemView.extend({
    tagName: 'a',
    attributes: {
        'class': 'dropdown-toggle',
        'data-toggle': 'dropdown',
        'href': '#'
    },

    initialize: function() {
        this.render();
    },

    render: function() {
        this.$el.html('test').after('<b>bam?</b>');

        return this;
    }
});
```

Anytime I call the render function and try to manipulate the data outside of the this.el that is set up on creation it is never appended after the tag.  Only inside (so I see 'test' inside the a tags but not the 'bam?'.  Anyone have any tips for dealing with sibling elements?

I also am not as experienced with Backbone / Marionette so there may be better way to attack this, I am just not sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would use a [Marionette.CompositeView](https://github.com/marionettejs/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.compositeview.md) to do this and not override render at all.

```
DropDownItemView = Backbone.Marionette.ItemView.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  template: "#dropdown-item-template"
});

DropDownMenuView = Backbone.Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
  itemView: DropDownItemView,
  // specify a jQuery selector to put the itemView instances in to
  itemViewContainer: "ul",
  template: "#drop-down-menu-template"
});
```

A general rule of thumb that I have found using Backbone.Marionette is that if you are manipulating the $el then there is usually a better way to do it.